# Populating Swing JComboBox from Enum

Tags: java, swing, enums, jcombobox

I would like to populate a `java.swing JComboBox` with values from an `Enum`.

e.g.

```
public enum Mood { HAPPY, SAD, AWESOME; }
```

and have these three values populate a readonly `JComboBox`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

try:

```
new JComboBox(Mood.values());
```

Comment: This will return the exact name of the enum value. If you want more UI friendly names, JComboBox will use overridden toString() methods.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't want to (or can't) change initialization with default constructor, then you can use `setModel()` method:

```
JComboBox<Mood> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(Mood.values()));
```

Comment: Note [*Type Inference for Generic Instance Creation*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) and [generic model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html), new in Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @Pierre is good. Usually you use a DefaultComboBoxModel or a [ComboBoxModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) or bindings to the ComboBoxModel for more complex stuff.

By default a JComboBox is not editable.

Comment: This in no way answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using only the default constructor and without using `setModel()` method:

```
JComboBox<Mood> comboBox_mood = new JComboBox<>();
```